# Is there a way to modify the private variables of a child class using an inherited method in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a class Child that inherits from a class Parent. They both have a private instance variable named `a`. The parent class has a method to change the `a` variable.

`Parent.h`

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
class Parent {
public:
    Parent() {}
    ~Parent() {}

    virtual void changeA() {
        a++;
        std::cout << "Parent a: " << a << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int a = 0;
};
```

`Child.h`

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "Parent.h"

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child() {}
    ~Child() {}

    void changeA() {
        Parent::changeA();
        std::cout << "Child a: " << a << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int a = 0;
};
```

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include "Child.h"
#include "Parent.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Parent parent = Parent();
    Child child = Child();

    parent.changeA();
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    child.changeA();

    return 0;
}
```

`stdout`

```
Parent a: 1
---
Parent a: 1
Child a: 0
```

It seems as if the Child object also has a copy of the Parent object. How do I get the Parent's `changeA` method to change the Child's `a` instance variable?

Clarification:
I need this because I have a parent class `Entity` with two children `Enemy` and `Player`, and both classes need to use the same `init` method inherited from Entity.

Comment: You are explicitly calling the `Parent::changeA();` What do you expect?

Comment: Question: You want to have both `Parent::a` and `Child::a`? This is quite unusual. Anyway, `Parent::changeA` can't do the job because there's no way for `Parent` to know that `Child` even exists (But look up CRTP) or that it's not really a `Child2`, but if you make it `virtual` you could have `Child::changeA` do the work.

Comment: Side note: When a construct tor or destructor doesn't do anything, leave it out or explicitly default it. The compiler will autogenerate the correct code.

Comment: @user4581301, that is not quite true. The parent class *can* know of the child like it does in CRTP.

Comment: I don't see the code that displays `Parent a`, did you lose it in the copy/paste?

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks. The question has been edited.

Comment: @user4581301 How would I do that?

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I'm not seeing where you are coming from. You could forward-declare `Child`, but you're not gaining much. If I'm missing something, please fill me in.

Comment: If possible, get rid of the `init` method and make smarter constructors. The `Parent` constructor will be called as part of the `Child` constructor and make the problem go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent class knows nothing of any child. It can define a virtual method, and the child can override this method like that:

```cpp
class Child : public Parent {
    void changeA() override {
        // Here the Child::a will be changed:
        ++a;
        std::cout << "Child a: " << a << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int a = 0;
};
```

The `override` (or `final`) is an optional specifier, but it is the best practice to specify one.

There is however a way to let the parent know the child. That is called Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP):

```cpp
template<typename Child>
class Parent {
public:
    virtual void changeA() {
        // Here the Child::a is changed:
        static_cast<Child*>(this)->a++;
        std::cout << "Parent a: " << a << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int a = 0;
};

class Child : public Parent<Child> {
public:
    void changeA() override {
        Parent::changeA();
        std::cout << "Child a: " << a << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int a = 0;
};
```

The code above would not compile however because the `Child::a` is private, and the `Parent<Child>` has no access to this member. You may either make it public or make the `Parent` a `friend`:

```cpp
class Child : public Parent<Child> {
public:
    void changeA() override {
        Parent::changeA();
        std::cout << "Child a: " << a << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int a = 0;
    friend class Parent<Child>;
};
```

Overall I don't understand your intention, and the code is error prone. I guess there are better ways to solve your **actual** problem.

**Update:** another way to achieve the behavior is to store a reference in the `Parent`. You don't even need to make the method virtual in this case:

```cpp
class Parent {
public:
    Parent(int &a) : a(a) {}
    void changeA() {
        a++;
        std::cout << "Parent a: " << a << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int &a;
};

class Child : public Parent {
    Child() : Parent(a) {}

private:
    int a = 0;
};
```

In this case only one instance of the integer field is allocated, and the Parent uses the same data the Child stores.

Answer (score 0):

Make `Parent::changeA` a [`virtual` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) and add code to `Child::changeA` to modify `Child::a`. Quick example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Parent {
public:
    virtual ~Parent() {} // almost always want a virtual destructor
                         // Don't need it here, but if you find yourself 
                         // having to delete a Child through a Parent 
                         // pointer this is a must.

    virtual void changeA() { // virtual function at runtime the derived version, 
                             // if one exists, will be called instead of 
                             // Parent::changeA
        a++;
        std::cout << "Parent a: " << a << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int a = 0;
};


class Child : public Parent {
public:

    void changeA() override { // will be called in place of Parent::changeA 
                              // the override keyword will cause a compiler 
                              // error if no override takes place. Zero 
                              // runtime cost and saves debugging. Winning.
        Parent::changeA(); // modifies Parent::a
        a++; // modifies its Child::a
        std::cout << "Child a: " << a << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int a = 0;
};

int main() {
    Parent parent;
    Child child;

    parent.changeA();
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    child.changeA();

    return 0;
}
```

[Documentation for `override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override).

Comment: I don't want to rewrite the parent method's code in the child as well.

Comment: @ThuongVo you haven't  repeated. They are different `a`s and both need to be set. What you really need to ask though, is why do you have duplicated members?

Comment: The parent class is never really used, but it contains the shared code between its child classes. I want to share a method between child classes, and have one place to change that code. To get it to compile, I had to make duplicate members. The problems is that the code inherited doesn't change the child members.

Comment: You should explore that duplication. Odds are very good that you have what's called an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) You're may be asking a question about a problem with a solution when you should be asking about the problem the solution is failing to solve effectively.

Comment: So how do I share the code? After I got rid of the init method, the code still can't be shared between children because it seems that there is an instance of the parent object for each instance of the child object. The constructor code is modifying the variables of the parent instance for the child instance and not modifying the child instance's variables.

Comment: @ThuongVo, from what I can see, you do not need inheritance, but you need a template. That is a way to "share a method between child classes".

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Thank you for your answer. It was exactly what I needed. What would inheritance be useful for, however?

Comment: @ThuongVo, that is a long story. It is not possible to answer what would be the hammer useful for (because there are many different usage scenarios), but in many cases it is possible to answer when is shouldn't be used (e.g. where a saw should be used).